# Can I use another name instead ns1 in ns1.domain.com

Tags: dns

Can I use another name instead of ns1 in ns1.webdevelopernepal.net
I mean to say I want dipendra.webdevelopernepal.net instead of ns1.webdevelopernepal.net
and pradhan.webdevelopernepal.net instead of ns2.webdevelopernepal.net
Please help me out I am a newbie..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Yes!

Assuming you have access to the DNS settings and can add the appropriate A record or CNAME to point to dipendra.webdevelopernepal.net